# Sidenotes and footnotes not working in tufte class

Tags: footnotes, tufte

I am using the `tufte-book` class, and the `\footnote` and `\sidenote` commands do not seem to be working properly, while marginnotes work.

When I use either `\footnote{}` or `\sidenote{}` (no number, but this is, according to the manual, not required), I get two errors: missing number, treated as zero and illegal unit of meassure (pt inserted).

Code example:

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % lettertype met alle karakters
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\title{Footnotes and sidenotes}
\author{Ben}
\date{} 
\begin{document}


\maketitle

\section*{Footnotes and sidenotes}
Main text \footnote{Footnote text}

More main text \sidenote{Sidenote text}
\end{document}
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Ben, I've used it extensively but I don't think that your problem relates to the class specifically. One usually gets that on specifying a unit in an  option without specifying the unit. http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/length.html#tab:units shows the accepted units. Another problem might also be that you have an incorrectly defined table. As lockstep mentioned, a MWE will be infinitely helpful to identify your specific problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what was wrong through experimentation.

My original code looked like this:

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % lettertype met alle karakters
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\title{Footnotes and sidenotes}
\author{Ben}
\date{} 
\begin{document}


\maketitle

\section*{Footnotes and sidenotes}
Main text \footnote{Footnote text}

More main text \sidenote{Sidenote text}
\end{document}
```

When I was asked by @lockstep to provide an example, I removed what I thought to be irrelevant packages, but then it suddenly worked. It was soon clear that the package `footmisc` seems to be incomatible with `tufte-book`. Removing this package (and resorting to the manual option of `\section[Sectiontitle without footnotes]{Sectiontitle \footnote{Footnote}}` works.

Comment: The `footmisc` package redefines the `\footnote` command, overwriting the Tufte-LaTeX definition of `\footnote`. So, as you discovered, the `footmisc` package and Tufte-LaTeX document classes are incompatible.